# WSO2 - Move Databases to new Instance, APIM cannot find reference

Tags: sql-server, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a WSO2 API Manager 1.6.0 setup with SVN repository syncing. I recently had to move my databases off a SQL Server instance to another SQL Server instance. The databases moved effortlessly, however, the API's are not showing like they used to before you log into the store page. I am also receiving these errors:

```java
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-10-15 09:38:54,517]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2014-10-15 09:38:54,517-0500] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-10-15 09:38:54,710]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2014-10-15 09:38:54,710-0500] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-10-15 09:38:55,740] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO} -  Unable to find the API: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.model.APIIdentifier@3b581336 in the database {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO}
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-10-15 09:38:55,744] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject} -  Error from Registry API while getting Recently Added APIs Information {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Unable to find the API: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.model.APIIdentifier@3b581336 in the database
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.getAPIID(ApiMgtDAO.java:4656)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.getAverageRating(ApiMgtDAO.java:3577)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.getAverageRating(ApiMgtDAO.java:3547)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.getAverageRating(APIUtil.java:1730)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.getAPI(APIUtil.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.getAPIs(APIConsumerImpl.java:1614)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.getRecentlyAddedAPIs(APIConsumerImpl.java:670)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIConsumer.getRecentlyAddedAPIs(UserAwareAPIConsumer.java:34)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject.jsFunction_getRecentlyAddedAPIs(APIStoreHostObject.java:538)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.api.c1._c_anonymous_1(/store/modules/api/recently-added.jag:8)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.api.c1.call(/store/modules/api/recently-added.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_5(/store/modules/api/module.jag:19)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.api.c0.call(/store/modules/api/module.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.api.recently_added.c0._c_anonymous_2(/store/site/blocks/api/recently-added/block.jag:10)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.api.recently_added.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/api/recently-added/block.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_26(/store/jagg/jagg.jag:198)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0.call(/store/jagg/jagg.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_27(/store/jagg/jagg.jag:258)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0.call(/store/jagg/jagg.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_26(/store/jagg/jagg.jag:210)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0.call(/store/jagg/jagg.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_27(/store/jagg/jagg.jag:258)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0.call(/store/jagg/jagg.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_26(/store/jagg/jagg.jag:193)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0.call(/store/jagg/jagg.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_38(/store/jagg/jagg.jag:423)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0.call(/store/jagg/jagg.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.c0._c_anonymous_1(/store/site/pages/list-apis.jag:19)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.c0.call(/store/site/pages/list-apis.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.c0._c_script_0(/store/site/pages/list-apis.jag:10)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.c0.call(/store/site/pages/list-apis.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.c0.call(/store/site/pages/list-apis.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.c0.exec(/store/site/pages/list-apis.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:570)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:432)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I'm not exactly sure what its not finding, because when I look at the contents of the database, they are the same as what is in the synapse-config/api/ folder. What is the API Manager process missing?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 API Manager loads APIs in the Store from registry database and API manager database. According to the error message,your APIs are in the registry database, but not in the API manager database. To find out the problem, check what is the database you have pointed as the 'WSO2AM_DB' data source inside AM_HOME/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasource.xml. Then please double check that you have correctly moved data from that data source in to new database.

Comment: Where at in the registry database would the API's be written to? I seem to have the API's in the carbondb, but I'm not seeing the API's in the sharedreg database; if that makes sense.